# Map value to specific color in seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, heatmap, seaborn

I am plotting a heatmap in Python with the seaborn package. The values I am plotting are discrete, they are the integers `-1`, `0`, and `1`.

I would like the cells in the heatmap with the value `-1` to show up green, those with `0` as yellow, and `1` as red.

Is it possible to specify this ruling in the `cubehelix_palette()` or `colour_palette()` functions?

Comment: See [Assign specific color to seaborn heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63392693/7758804)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

data = np.random.randint(-1, 2, (10,10)) # Random [-1, 0, 1] data
sns.heatmap(data, cmap=ListedColormap(['green', 'yellow', 'red']), annot=True)
```

which yields:

[image]

You can replace the strings `'green', 'yellow', 'red'` with hexcolors such as `'#FF0000'` (equivalent to `'red'`) or rgb colors such as `(1.,0.,0.)` (also equivalent to `'red'`).