# How to map a range of values to a specific colour with seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.6, seaborn

I wanted to map a range of values to a specific range of colours in a heatmap. For example, the range 1.0 - 2.0 will be plotted against the range of colours from `#2b8a44 - #00ff43`.

I have to plot multiple heatmaps iteratively so the range of numbers to the range of colours should **always** be the same and cannot change at every iteration.

An example to plot can be:

```
xa = [[5.45.45, 4.11, 4.054, 4.678, 13.854, 4.0098, 4],
 [1.75, 9.0943, 4.34, 3.34, 9.89, 1, 4.998],
 [4.76, 8.54, 1.34, 7.35, 1.2342, 4.0576, 8]]
```

The range of values will be till 18. That is is 1-2, 2-3.....17-18.

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918822/map-value-to-specific-colour-in-seaborn-heatmap) answer, unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: I commented on your last question already that you will need to use a `BoundaryNorm`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, I got it. I am not sure if you have commented as I could not see. Thanks!